# How to check that Xdebug remote debugging is set up correctly

Tags: php, debugging, ubuntu, xdebug, remote-debugging

I have searched the internet for a while now, but haven't found a possibility how to check if Xdebug is working correctly.
I have installed Xdebug on Ubuntu (like instructed on the xdebug homepage).
I use these settings (they are also shown in phpinfo() ):

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 500
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
```

So from this point is seems to be installed correctly. But my IDE (PhpStorm) does not connect, or xdebug does not run.. I don't know. I have nothing in the xdebug logs. I checked for open ports with `netstat -tulpn`, but no port 9000 is shown.

I have a similar setup on a machine on a local network, where Xdebug is working with the same settings fine. 
If I check for open ports with `netstat -tulpn` - I also do not see an open port for 9000, but still the debugger works. 
I also tried to check the port via `telnet` but this is not working on either server. 
I tried to check the port via `nmap -p 9000 myserver.com` but this is also not working on either server, so I guess it is also not relevant.

Any idea how I can check if the server is listening on port 9000, or find where my problem lies?
Thanks.

Comment: Try to turn on the profiler, to check, is xDebug working correctly. If there will be the profile files, than something bad in your phpstorm I think.

Comment: I don;t think that the profile proves it, as the profiles is started on the server, when the page loads, right? so without interaction of the IDE. I am searching for something to "ping" the server somehow to start the debug session